# Red Pill detect virtualization

Tags: c++, c, virtual-machine, virtualization

I am trying to detect if my Windows is running on Virtual Machine or not. I've found this C code which is known as Joanna Rutkowska's Red Pill:

```
int swallow_redpill () 
{
  unsigned char m[2+4], rpill[] = "\x0f\x01\x0d\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc3";
  *((unsigned*)&rpill[3]) = (unsigned)m;
  ((void(*)())&rpill)();
  return (m[5]>0xd0) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

But when I am running it in my VC++ Project it fails on line

```
  ((void(*)())&rpill)();
```

with message: Access violation executing location 0x003AFCE8.
Am I doing smth wrong?

Comment: You try to use the data in `rpill` as a function. However, normal data in a program should not be executable, so it can't be "called". Furthermore, what if you're on a 64-bit system where the size of addresses are 64 bits? The `unsigned` type is equal to `unsigned int` which on all modern standard PC platforms is a 32-bit type, so the address of `m` might be truncated when you "patch" it into the code.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude does it mean that this isn't working method? or is there any way to make this solution working on both x86 and x64 systems?

Comment: The pointer-issue could easily be solved by building your program as a 32-bit executable. That will not solve the problem with the data not being executable though, and I do not know how to solve that.

Comment: That approach was invented over a decade ago, and is very specific to particular VMMs of the time--VMWare Workstation and Virtual PC. It depends on the way the VMMs manage guest memory. It will not work with modern virtualization techniques (EPT and NPT, which are themselves nearly a decade old).

Answer (score 5):

Apparently the sample code is trying to execute a sequence of machine instructions that behave differently inside *some* virtual machines than on *some" real hardware. Note that other VMs may not be detectable with such simple approach.

The reason why the code fails to execute is that on modern OSes you can not execute data sections. You would need to specifically put that piece of code into an executable section, or change data section to be executable.

From [Joanna Rutkowska](https://web.archive.org/web/20110929075510/http://invisiblethings.org/papers/redpill.html) the actual writer of the code:

> NOTE: this program will fail on systems with PAX/X^W/grsecurity, protection (as it was pointed out by Brad Spengler) since the rpill variable is not marked as executable. To make it run in such systems, mprotect() should be used to mark rpill with PROT_EXEC attribute. Another solution would be to just use asm() keyword instead of shellcode-like buffer. However, this program should be rather considered as a skeleton to build into your own shellcode, rather then standalone production class tool;) My goal was to make it as simple and portable as possible. That's why I didn't use asm() nor mprotect() since they are system or compiler dependent.

Answer (score 1):

```c
#include <windows.h>

unsigned char m[2+4], rpill[] = "\x0f\x01\x0d\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc3";
int swallow_redpill () 
{
  unsigned int old;
  VirtualProtect(rpill, 8, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &old);
  *((unsigned*)&rpill[3]) = (unsigned)m;
  ((void(*)())&rpill)();
  return (m[5]>0xd0) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

should do the trick on Windows. Make sure you run it built on Win32 if you have a x64 machine.

Comment: That looks wrong to me: don't you need to VirtualProtect rpill not old? Even if rpill was on the stack not global (so in the initialised data segment?) the 8 might not cover the whole of rpill + alignment, although I guess the chances of it spanning a page and your running into trouble with that are slim.

Answer (score 0):

This is handwritten for x86 and doesn't account for NX stacks that's a common hardening mechanism in modern compilers. A more portable code for fetching IDTR via SIDT that works on amd64:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct {
    unsigned short limit;
    unsigned long base;
} __attribute__((packed)) idtr;

int main() {
    asm("sidt %0" : "=m" (idtr));
    printf("%lx %x\n", idtr.base, idtr.limit);
    return 0;
}
```